# Magento import plain text password

Tags: magento, csv, import, passwords

I need to import about 15.000 Users into Magento through CSV-Import. In the CSV-File the passwords are stored as plain text. If I import this plain text passwords in magento the login is not working (Error: wrong username or password)

What is the right way to import customers with plain text password in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer->setData('password', {clear password})
```

or

```
$customer->setPassword({clear password})
```

will encode the password correctly.

Comment: thanks for you reply, but I'm pretty a newbie, so where should i put this line of code?

Comment: ok... for 15k+ lines import, I thought you made your own code :)  I do not know if it works with the basic csv import. i would check if the encoding is good for the csv.